# Delayed payment without primary receiver

Tags: paypal, delay, payment

I need to have delayed payments using PayPal from one customer of the site to another customer. Receiver should get the funds 2 weeks later.
I wanted to use Delayed Chained Payments from Adaptive Payments and set primary receiver amount to 0, but it didn't work.
Are there any options of delayed payments without primary receiver? (not chained delayed payments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're doing a chained payment the primary receiver amount should be the full amount of the payment.  Then the secondary receiver would be whatever amount they should get.

If you want to push the the entire amount, then instead of setting the primary amount to 0, set them both to the same thing.

I'm only mostly sure that will work for you.  You'll need to give it a shot and see, but if I remember correctly that's how chained payments works with the amounts.